# Avoiding unfair exchange rates on money earned in the Czech Republic as a non-EU citizen

Tags: bank-account, foreign-exchange, currency, european-union

I'm a British citizen. Last year I worked a summer job in the Czech Republic, an EU country, while on a scientific research visa. I was paid in Czech koruna (CZK). [As of February 2020, I am not an EU citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit), so I could not open a bank account in the country. This meant I had to be paid to my UK bank account, which applied a vastly inflated foreign exchange rate of 32 CZK = 1 GBP. The rate at which various independent exchanges were buying CZK at the time was around 28 CZK = 1 GBP. This means I lost around 13% of my income after tax to unnecessary foreign exchange rates.

I am planning to take the same job this year. Short of getting my wages paid to another person's (Czech) bank account, how can I avoid these unfair foreign exchange rates when being paid in CZK?

Comment: Can you be paid in cash?

Comment: @DJClayworth Unfortunately not.

Comment: *I am not an EU citizen, so I could not open a bank account in the country.* - is this true? Sounds very strange, there's a large amount of non-EU citizens working in EU countries, can none of them bank locally? See this: https://blog.foreigners.cz/how-to-open-a-bank-account/

Comment: @littleadv because my job was only for a couple of months, I was only on a short-stay Schengen visa (type C) which isn't enough to open a bank account, as opposed to a long-stay (type D) visa. I know this, because I actually went into Raiffeisen and tried to open one, but was told that I wasn't allowed to.

Comment: @user19642323 I'm not sure what other answers you're expecting here... Try another bank? Ask if your employer has some banking relationships with a bank that will support them? Shop around with British banks to see if any can offer you a EUR account or has better rates?

Comment: @littleadv I guess my questions are (1) are there CZK accounts I can hold as a British citizen _and_ be paid into from the Czech republic? (From my digging so far, I think the answer is no.) And, (2) is there a website which lets me compare UK banks' exchange rates for receiving in a foreign currency (these are often not as public as for those for spending in a different currency) and finally (3) is there some other method that I haven't thought of? I wouldn't be asking if I knew what answers to expect :)

Comment: yeah, that makes sense :)

Comment: Have you looked into Wise/Revolut? They offer more competitive rates. It looks like you could get CZK sent to your British Wise account, so still an international transfer but you wouldn't get ripped off on the exchange: https://wise.com/help/articles/2935927/how-do-i-use-my-gbp-account-details

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica wise.com isn't particularly useful, because it doesn't accept payments in CZK, it only lets you hold and top up an account in CZK. Revolut looks more promising...

Comment: @user19642323 I was looking at the bit in the page I linked that says "How to receive other currencies to your GBP account details: You can receive 17 different currencies to your GB Swift/global account details: [...]CZK[...] Deposits will be settled in the currency that we receive from the sender." - but I have no personal experience of trying this.

Comment: I suggest inquiring of other UK banks/financial institutions what premium they place on exchange rates. 10%+ is excessive. Then move your account.